# MongoDB and geospatial queries: unknown geo specifier: $geometry: null

Tags: mongodb, 2dsphere, mongodb-geospatial

i'm experimenting with mongodb and geospatial queries. I made the following collection:

```
shape> db.shape.find()
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61ab50d2056b5357b5e23e56"),
    name: 'Point1',
    structure: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ 2.5, 2.5 ] }
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61ab5337056b5357b5e23e57"),
    name: 'Point2',
    structure: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ 5, 5 ] }
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61ab533e056b5357b5e23e58"),
    name: 'Point3',
    structure: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ 9, 9 ] }
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61ab5b4d056b5357b5e23e64"),
    name: 'square',
    structure: {
      type: 'Polygon',
      coordinates: [ [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 5 ], [ 5, 5 ], [ 5, 0 ], [ 0, 0 ] ] ]
    }
  }
]
```

then i tried the following:

```
var square = db.shape.find({name :"square"});
db.shape.find({structure : { $geoWithin : { $geometry : square.structure}}});
```

and i get this error:

```
MongoServerError: unknown geo specifier: $geometry: null
```

why is $geometry null?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `findOne` instead of `find`

Comment: i tried, but i still get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While processing the query, `square.structure` is getting replaced with `null` because you are trying to access that variable in wrong way.

In that `square` variable you are storing results returned by `find()` method.

`find()` method returns a cursor and we need to use cursor methods (like `forEach`) to access the containing documents. Where as `findOne()` returns a single document which can be accessed directly.

So, you can:

1. Use `findOne()` instead of `find()` or
2. Use cursor method like `square.forEach(function(mydoc){<iterate through cursor here>})`

I have copied your data and tested your query with `findOne()` and it worked well.

Comment: thanks, you are right, find() returns a cursor, that's why it didnt' work.

Comment: ahhhhh. Wish I had known this six hours ago when I began executing my query . . . lesson learned.